# Column count of mysql.proc is wrong

Tags: mysql, linux, xampp

Im attempting to deal with a corrupted database with little success, when I try to alter this table I am giving the error

```
 Column count of mysql.proc is wrong
```

Looking up this error online gives me many results all saying the same variation of, you must run

```
mysql_upgrade
```

However when I run that I am greeted with

```
The mysql_upgrade client is now deprecated. The actions executed by the upgrade client are  now done by the server.
To upgrade, please start the new MySQL binary with the older data directory. Repairing user tables is done automatically. Restart is not required after upgrade.
The upgrade process automatically starts on running a new MySQL binary with an older data directory. To avoid accidental upgrades, please use the --upgrade=NONE option with the MySQL binary. The option --upgrade=FORCE is also provided to run the server upgrade sequence on demand.
It may be possible that the server upgrade fails due to a number of reasons. In that case, the upgrade sequence will run again during the next MySQL server start. If the server upgrade fails repeatedly, the server can be started with the --upgrade=MINIMAL option to start the server without executing the upgrade sequence, thus allowing users to manually rectify the problem.
```

However again another problem occurs any time I try to log into mysql from the command line, all attempts to log in respond with

```
Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) when trying to connect
```

This does make sense as localhost/phpmyadmin works just fine and I can create new tables or databases but I just cant alter the corrupt database

Any help is appreciated this is XAMPP on Ubuntu

Comment: mysql - ver 8.0.25
xampp- ver 8.0.6

Comment: uninstalling mysql and xampp then reinstalling did nothing as the broken database still appeared when I reinstalled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by just rm -rf the folder in the /var/mysql folder in xampp